# Why mpmath slower than gsl on the same precision? And Which results are right?

Tags: floating-point, gsl, arbitrary-precision, mpmath

I simplely test the clausen function of [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/zeta.html?highlight=clsin#mpmath.clsin) and [gsl](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Clausen-Functions.html#Clausen-Functions). The code is below:

```
mp.prec = 53
time_begin = time.time()
print "mpmath results:"
print clsin(2,3.1415926535897327)
print "time1:"
print (time.time() - time_begin)
time_begin = time.time()
print "gsl results:"
print gsl_sf_clausen(3.1415926535897327)
print "time2"
print (time.time() - time_begin)
```

The results are below:

```
mpmath results:
4.19482951966115e-14
time1:
0.00391387939453
gsl results:
4.18544219761e-14
time2
2.69412994385e-05
```

From the results I found on the same precision, the results are very different(mpmath:4.19... but gsl:4.18...), I want to know which one is more accurarcy?
And the mpmath more than 100 times slower than gsl_sf_clausen on the same precision, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, Clausen function is exactly 0 at x = pi. You are feeding it a number that is extremely close to pi. Depending on how the evaluation of Clausen's function is implemented, the computation at this point may involve [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) due to nearly complete cancellation of terms.

Presumably, gsl and mpmath don't have identical implementation of Clausen's function, so their running time and their outputs differ. This is not unusual. Even for something as seemingly straightforward as finding the inverse of a matrix, you'll sometimes encounter different packages returning different results, while operating at the  same precision level.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=clausen+function+at+3.1415926535897327) returns 4.19620646966946940430... e-14, which is closer to mpmath value. And `mpmath` itself will agree with WolframAlpha if the precision is increased.

```
>>> mp.dps = 25
>>> clsin(2, mpf('3.1415926535897327'))
mpf('4.196206469668926047718406898e-14')
```

Which brings us to another point: `mpmath` is designed to work with any given precision of floating point numbers, while `gsl` appears to use double precision floats (I don't really know its internals). So it's no surprise that the algorithm of `mpmath`, designed with the thought that very high accuracy may be required of it, takes longer to run.